# How to scroll down ListView to the bottom of it after button tapping (using scrollToIndex for instance)? NativeScript-Vue

Tags: javascript, listview, nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-telerik-ui

Maybe it seems to be an easy task, but I don't really know how to solve it.

I have a ListView component in my NativeScript-vue application. And I need the ListView to scroll down to the end of it after I've tapped on a button.

I tried this:

```
<ListView ref="listViewEl" for="item in items">
<TextView :text="item.value"></TextView>
</ListView>
...

tappingButton() {
    this.$refs.listViewEl.scrollIndexTo(lastIndexScroll);
}
```

But it doesn't work and I recieve an error:

> this.$refs.listViewEl.scrollToIndex is not a function.

It also doesn't work for other methods like "scrollTo, smoothScrollToPosition, scrollToVerticalOffset, etc."

What Do I miss?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `.nativeView`. In order to access the actual `ListView` element from the reference, you have to call the `.nativeView` property.

```
tappingButton() {
   this.$refs.listViewEl.nativeView.scrollToIndex(lastIndexScroll);
}
```

Also the method name is `scrollToIndex`